# iPad magazine ap content grabbing?

Tags: iphone, ipad

looking to develop a magazine app similar to Time and GQ.
Can anyone tell me what method they are using to pull the content in?

Answer (score 1):

They are probably just reading an RSS or Atom feed. At least that is what I would do if I were to make such an app.

Comment: I thought about the XML feed route... but can't seem to find anything verifying that is the method they are doing, and if not then what method they are.

Comment: JSON possibly? Frankly it really doesn't matter how they do it as long as you can display the content appropriately. The "best" solution really comes down to what you have available. If you already have a well established site with RSS / Atom feeds in place then it makes sense to use them. If not you are free to look at other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The Time app is using Woodwing Technology, they have an interesting video how that you author the content in InDesign - http://www.woodwing.com/en/digital-magazine/ipad-now - but they don't disclose how the app retrieves the content from the server. I am looking into developing such an app also, so I would like to know how they do it...

Comment: Yes yes, Luc.
quoting from a page off of what you sent - http://www.woodwing.com/en/digital-magazine/ipad-tools -
 "An optional Delivery Server solution allows you to publish new issues which the user can directly download to the iPad from within the reader app, opening up subscription models for content."

I guess we're both looking for their method of "Delivery Server solution"

Answer (score 0):

I agree rss and atom are the simplest options but are they the best?  I've looked at a few of these magazines this weekend and some of the styling is just as impressive as the content options.  I'd like to talk to someone that's looked at the development of one of these setups and get some specifics.

Comment: As i said to Simon - XML i've looked at it. Just wondering - as you seem to be - if there isn't another method I'm not aware of.